# How can I get the original key map of a numbered key in a keypress event with shift?

Tags: javascript, events, keyboard, keypress

I want to be able to get the value of a numbered key on a onKeypress event that is done with shift. I'm trying to make a web app that links different actions with the  keys 123...9 and also shift-123...9. The problem is that when I get the keypress event with shift, I only can get the shift-value and if shift is true.

e.g. shift-1

```
shiftKey: true
key: "!"
```

I want to find a way to get the value 1 from "!". I'm worried also about other keyboards that might have different characters other than "!" when shift-1 is pressed. Like AZERTY keyboard.
http://mentalfloss.com/article/52483/6-non-qwerty-keyboard-layouts

How can I get the original value of a shift-keypress event as though shift was not pressed?

update to comment response:

```
@HostListener('document:keypress', ['$event'])
handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
  let keyNumber = Number.parseInt(event.key);
  if (keyNumber !== NaN && keyNumber !== 0) {
    if (event.shiftKey === false && keyNumber <= this.documents.length) {
      // use number to access some array
      this.currentDocument = this.documents[--keyNumber];
    } else if (keyNumber <= this.currentDocument.toc.length) { // I'll see if they go past 10..
      // PROBLEM HERE trying to get number to also access an array
      this.routeToFragment(this.currentDocument.toc[--keyNumber].slug); // this is NaN until I can convert "!@#$%..("
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried. The part about *"only can get the shift-value"* doesn't really make sense

Comment: I just posted an example of my code just now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyboard events have the `code` property as part of their event object - this will return the key that's pressed, ignoring any modifier keys.

Example:

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
  console.log({ code: event.code })
})

/*
[press shift + 1] => // { code: 'Digit1' }
[press shift + /] => // { code: 'Slash' }
*/
```

Comment: Will this code value be the same universally on all different keyboards?

Comment: MDN has some good documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code. TL;DR Yes

Comment: Thanks for the link and your response. This is very helpful to me. : )